# Is there some type of GPS caching for iOS?

Tags: ios, flutter

My app needs to obtain the GPS location of the user. I have implemented it correctly (am using Flutter) and it works fine when I test it home, but when I change the position it first shows the same nearby objects from the last time, then when I restart it, it shows them properly.

This happens only on iOS I think, but I've tested it only with one Android device that were connected to the iPhone wifi, so am not sure it didn't use the wifi precision, tonight I'll test it again with it's own mobile data.
So my question is if there exist some type of GPS cache on iOS and if there is, how to clear it when open the app.

Comment: You need to get the last (newest location), I don't now anything about flutter but it most likely uses the iOS Location service so [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_standard_location_service) might be worth reading, see the section "Receiving Location Updates" for your specific issue

Comment: Thanks, I’ll take a closer look at this.